# footer not showing, but when press inspect element it is.

Tags: php, css, wordpress

On my website http://landgravecabo.com i do not see the footer. But for some reason when i press inspect element on google chrome it suddenly appears. Already checked the style.css but there is no problem. But my footer area has not much info maybe that could be a problem? this is the info from my footer:

```
/**
 *  (c) king-theme.com
 */

    king::path( 'footer' );

/*
    . change footer via theme-panel
    . location in themes/aaika/templates/footer/__file__    
*/
?>
    </div><!-- #main -->
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please explain to me how this happened?

Comment: I cant see it at all with dev tools lol.. reason the `effHidden` class causes the wrapper div to have `display:none` on it, its probably a miscalculation of the lazy loading because of the colossal amount of scripts/plugins your throwing at it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not related with inspect element in Google Chrome. It is about your responsive design. When you narrow the screen, footer is visible. If you want to make it visible at all widths, delete this code:

```
.effHidden,.effHidden *{visibility:hidden}
```

You can find it in http://www.landgravecabo.com/wp-content/themes/aloom/core/assets/css/animate.css

Comment: Thanks Onur Uslu, That worked for me, now i can see thefooter again. appreciate your fast answer